# I have a doubt in finding workdone by a negative charge in moving it in presence of positive charge

Tags: electrostatics

Let say I have a positive charge at the origin. Now imagine I  get a negative charge from $X=10~\text{cm}$ to $X=2~\text{cm}.$ By common sense we can say that the work done by us will be negative as we are doing work in the direction of the force. But let's try to prove this by calculations. Here I don't understand why I don't get the answer correctly.

$$W_\text{by electric field} = \int(F dr \cos\theta  ).$$

$$W_\text{by us}=  -\int(F dr \cos\theta) \\=  -\int k\frac{q^2}{r^2} dr.$$   As $$F=k\frac{q^2}{r^2}\;.$$

$$W_\text{by us}=  -kq^2 \int\frac{1}{r^2} dr.\\=  -kq^2 (-1/r)\\=    kq^2(1/r)$$

Now plugging the limits: lower limit: $10~\text{cm}$ and upper limit: $2~\text{cm},$ as I move from $X=10~\text{cm}\; \to \; X=2~\text{cm}.$

After pluging in the limits we will get the answer to be -ve ( remember lower limit is 10cm). But how we got negative answer from calculations? Actually it should be positive.

I asked about this to my physics teacher. He said we need to give an extra negative sign while placing down the limits. But he was in a hurry so he didn't explained me the reason. Please can any one explain me the reason of placing an extra negative sign according to my physics teacher.

Comment: *"As F=kq^2/r^2"* - think *carefully* about that step.

Answer (score 0):

It is the cosine term that makes the difference.Remember that the force being applied by the field is towards the origin.You are applying a force to keep the negative charge in equilibrium, **the force being directed away from the origin**.So while you do move towards X=2cm,but the force you are applying is actually preventing that work from really happening.Hence you get the -ve sign while calculating the work done 'by us'.
The reason we place an additional -ve sign is due to the fact that **potential decreases as we move in the direction of an electric field**,in accordance to the formula E=-dV/dr